# Web frontend to spamassassin for service providers?

Tags: spam, spamassassin, amavis

I would like a frontend to spamassassin/amavis (or alike) which can let customers manage their own domains/settings. I do not look for hosted services. I do not mind licensing fees, but I do like open source. Not sure how many e-mails pass our servers today, but not more than 100k per 24h period I believe.

Anyone have got recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had incredible success with Barracuda's "[spam firewall](http://www.barracudanetworks.com/ns/products/spam_overview.php)" product, which you could offer to your customers as you describe.  It's a Linux appliance using a primarily Open Source stack.  I have built similar stacks myself on several occasions but I have yet to run across an Open Source Web frontend for the end users to manage the spam portion of it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've been reading about their L7 loadbalancer. They seem pretty interesting.

Answer (score 1):

there is a product called maia mailguard. It is a webbased (PHP/perl) management system based on amavisd-new and spamassassin. I used the release 1.0.0rc5 successfully a few years ago on a mailserver with different domains.

Answer (score 0):

You could try webmin/usermin. I haven't used it myself but i stumbled upon it the other day:

"Now there is both a Webmin and a Usermin version available. With Webmin the systemwide policy can be configured, with Usermin individual users can set their personal settings."